# Is possible use silent push to wake up APP and get the VOIP call?

Tags: ios, swift3, silentpush

if My app works at background, can I use silent push to wake app and get the VOIP call?

I used "jpush" to post a silent push which can work when connecting my idevice with Xcode and run APP.

If my idevice doesn't run APP with Xcode, I can not receive the silent push at background (only receive at foreground.)

Is it possible to use silent push to wake up APP and get VOIP call?

Did I get something wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your application does VoIP calling then it's possible to use [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit):

> #### Overview
>
> The PushKit framework sends specific types of notifications — such as VoIP invitations, [...] — directly to your app for processing. [...]
>
> Unlike user notifications, which are supported by the [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework, PushKit notifications are never presented to the user — they don't present badges, alerts, or sounds.
>
> PushKit notifications offer the following advantages over user notifications:
>
> - If your app isn't running, the system automatically launches it upon receiving the notification. [...] For more information, see [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications).
> - Your app is given runtime to process the notification, even if it's running in the background.
> - [...]

Comment: One other added benefit of pushkit is if you have force quit, still it would launch the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I can't use APNS  silent push to wake up APP, It's only receive at foreground. 
I will try PushKit to wake up APP.